# Multiple PDO queries in a script

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to figure out best practices for running multiple SQL queries using PDO in a single script.  The database connection is made at the beginning of the script, but then I need to make multiple different queries. What I'm doing currently (which I'm not sure is best practice) is:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$DBHOST.';dbname='.$DBNAME.';charset=UTF-8', $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD);

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT count(*) as total from bande_ips WHERE ip=:ip");
$query->bindValue(':ip', $_SESSION['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$query = NULL;
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from failed_login WHERE IP=:ip and email=:email");
$query->bindValue(':ip', $_SESSION['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

as you can see i prepare two seperate queries in a single script. But I started setting `$query = NULL;` as the script was confusing the seperate queries beforehand (it was expecting parameters of an old query which i was no longer calling, which led me to this uncertainty of this being best practices or not.)

I just want to confirm this is best practice before I continue migrating to PDO.

Comment: I'd suggest to use different variable names, as this can be misleading and error-prone -but if you do so, avoid using `query1`, `query2`...

Comment: @tmuguet I personally don't see the benefit of this. It looks like an unneccesary memory usage to me. Care to explain why?

Comment: First of all, a variable name should indicate its purpose/content: what does it query ? Secondly, as I said, it's error-prone. Example: from what you said, without `$query = NULL`, it will fail. If you come back in your code in a few months, you might forget why `$query = NULL` was there (as you didn't comment it) and delete it; or you might forget to add it if you add a new query. It can also cause you trouble if you want to do refactoring. Finally, if you are so worried about memory consumption, you can use `unset($query)` once you're done with it.

Comment: @tmuguet Actually, as indicated in an answer below, it works without `$query = NULL`, that was an error on my part with the code. :)

Comment: @JimmyBanks Well, that was just an example. In this case, there are maybe no obvious issues reusing a variable. But that doesn't mean it's OK ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the script was confusing the seperate queries beforehand (it was expecting parameters of an old query which i was no longer calling)

This is the problem with your program flow in some other code. Most likely run in a loop.

As for the code you posted here, there is no need to set `$query` into `NULL` - it will be overwritten by the next line anyway.

Please note that valid charset for mysql is `utf8`, not `utf-8`

Comment: Yeah, that is correct I had an issue in the code that was resulting in the error, and setting `$query = NULL` wasn't actually doing anything useful.